# How can I run grunt-contrib-symlink in a 'check' mode to see if has been run?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, symlink

We're using `[grunt-contrib-symlink](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-symlink) to define some links. I don't want it to run every time, but I want it to be helpful to people who are new to the system.

My question is: **How can I run grunt-contrib-symlink in a 'check' mode to see if has been run?**